# Holding one's breath while scuba diving

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, everyday-life, fluid-statics

Recently when I went scuba diving, the instructor told me that it would be extremely fatal to a scuba diver to hold his breath during the dive.  I searched up on the internet and came across Boyle's law ($PV = c$).  However, I am still unable to comprehend the explanation.  Perhaps someone can provide me with a more detailed and easier to understand explanation?

Comment: There's no problem if you hold your breath under water, but you could seriously injure your lungs if you try to hold your breath while ascending to the surface in a panic.

Comment: Yes, @jameslarge that was what i meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem, the deeper you go, the higher the pressure, say that initially you're at a depth where the pressure is $P_1$. You then breath in a volume $V_1$ or air and hold your breath while swimming up.

You do so until you reach a depth where the pressure is lower $P_2 < P_1$, according to Boyle's law

$$
P_1 V_1 = P_2 V_2 \tag{1}
$$

or equivalently

$$
V_2 = \left(\frac{P_1}{P_2}\right)V_1 > V_1 \tag{2}
$$

That is: the air in your lungs is going to expand which may cause some serious issues. For instance, bubbles can go into your blood stream, or they can rupture.

To give you a quick example, if you inhale at a depth of $10$ m ($P = 2$ atm), and them hold your breath up to the surface Eqn (2) tells you that your lungs should increase twice its size! Look at [this](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/other/games/depth_press) link